# Error when trying to execute man command with execv function : "man: can't execute cat: No such file or directory"

Tags: c, linux, shell

I am writing code for simple shell in C, and for some unknown reason I am getting error when trying to execute man command, while commands like ls, cat or other works fine. I want to have function for searching path of command.

This is error:

```
man: can't execute cat: No such file or directory
man: command exited with status 255: (cd /usr/share/man && /usr/lib/man-db/zsoelim) | (cd /usr/share/man && /usr/lib/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t ISO-8859-1//IGNORE) | (cd /usr/share/man && tbl) | (cd /usr/share/man && nroff -mandoc -rLL=88n -rLT=88n -Tutf8)
```

```c
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *searchPath(char *cmd) {
    int poljelen = 2;
    char **stringovi = malloc(poljelen * sizeof(char*));
    char *path = getenv("PATH");

    int i = 0;
    while((stringovi[i] = strsep(&path, ":")) != NULL) {
        i++;
        if (i >= poljelen) {
            poljelen = poljelen + i;
            stringovi = realloc(stringovi, poljelen * sizeof(char*));
            if (stringovi == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s", "Alloc error\n");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    stringovi[i] = '\0';
    i = 0;
    while(*stringovi[i] != '\0') {
        int pathlen = strlen(stringovi[i]);
        int cmdlen = strlen(cmd);
        char path[pathlen + cmdlen + 2];

        strcpy(path, stringovi[i]);
        strcat(path, "/");
        strcat(path, cmd);
        if (access(path, F_OK) == 0) {
            char *pathname = malloc(sizeof(char) * (pathlen + cmdlen + 2));
            if (!pathname) {
                return NULL;
            }
            strcpy(pathname, path);
            pathname[strlen(pathname)] = '\0';
            return pathname;
        }
        else {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    char *tokens[3];
    tokens[0] = "man"; //if you put here "ls"
    tokens[1] = "ls";  // and here "-al" its working
    tokens[2] = NULL;
    char *pathh = searchPath(tokens[0]);

    if (pathh == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: command not found\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char stringg[strlen(pathh) + 1];
    strcpy(stringg, pathh);

    pid_t childP;
    int status = 0;
    childP = fork();
    if (childP == 0) {
        if (execv(stringg, tokens) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: execv failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else if (childP == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: fork failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        waitpid(childP, &status, WUNTRACED);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried for debugging? Did you run your program in a debugger and inspect your variables? Do you path variables hold the expected values?

Comment: @Gerhardh The use of `strsep()` corrupts the `PATH` envval.

Comment: environment variables for the new process are set by the `extern char** environ`. It probably does not contain anything in your case. Either use it to set up PATH or better use an `execv?e` function.

Comment: Why are you searching `PATH` yourself instead of using `execvp`?

Comment: @Serge `execv()` [will just copy the parent's environment](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/execve.html): "For those forms not containing an `envp` pointer (`execl()`, `execv()`, `execlp()`, and `execvp()`), the environment for the new process image shall be taken from the external variable `environ` in the calling process."  Which is the problem here - that environment gets corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `strsep()` corrupts your `PATH` environment variable.

Per [the Linux `strsep()` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html):

> ... this function finds the first token in
> the string `*stringp`, that is delimited by one of the bytes in the
> string `delim`.  This token is terminated by overwriting the
> delimiter with a null byte (`'\0'`) ...

By calling `strsep()` with the value returned from `getenv("PATH")` you corrupt your `PATH` environment variable, leaving it as only the first component of the original value.

You should make a *copy* of the value returned from `getenv("PATH")` and split that into tokens.